# Styles dont work in second table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little problem with the tables I am using on my page.

The styles I defined for the `<th>` works in my first table, but in the second one it is not working.

`<th style="width:10px">Number</th>` for the table `employee_grid1` has a `width:10px`.
The same `<th>` in `employee_grid2` is much larger.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="" role="tabpanel" data-example-id="togglable-tabs">
  <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs bar_tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab_content1" id="home-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">1</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#tab_content2" role="tab" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab_content1" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
      <table id="employee_grid1" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width:10px">Number</th>
            <th style="width:50px">Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th style="width:100px"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_content2" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
      <table id="employee_grid2" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width:10px">Number</th>
            <th style="width:50px">Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th style="width:100px"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe its necessary for the solution. The table is filled with the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#employee_grid1').DataTable({
      "bprocessing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": {
        "url": "response1.php",
        "type": "POST",
        "error": function(){
          $("#employee_grid_processing").css("display","none");
        }
      },
      "columnDefs": [ 
        { "targets": 3, "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { return  '<p>'+data+'</p>'; } }              
      ]                 
    });   
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#employee_grid2').DataTable({
      "bprocessing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": {
        "url": "response2.php",
        "type": "POST",
        "error": function(){
          $("#employee_grid_processing").css("display","none");
        }
      },
      "columnDefs": [ 
        { "targets": 3, "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { return  '<p>'+data+'</p>'; } }              
      ]                 
    });   
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with a working code snippet? thanks!

Comment: please post the `css` code file as well. The additional classes and `aria` could be what's causing this

Comment: please create fiddle for this.

Comment: I can see both tables with the same dimensions

Comment: @TheDarkKnight `aria-labelledby` does not cause issues with `css`. More from [here](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#state_prop_def)

Comment: The classes that you use look like it came from Bootstrap, so I added a CDN for it, just roll it back if I am wrong

Comment: now I can't see the second table on your code snippet

Comment: Tab `2` is not opening for some reason

Comment: if you're using Bootstrap you'd need to include bootstrap.js library

Comment: Still not fixed

Comment: Just i check your issue but no any issue found as per your question check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Jaydeep_Mor/vyj5f0fp/).

Comment: Yes. Without the javascript it is working on jsfiddle. On my site I am using javascript and the response pages and I get no styles in the second table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code the table width is 100%, so better you will use % on table cells. Example:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="10%">Number</th>
    <th width="30%">Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th width="60%"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Or if you want the table width should be 100% and cells should be in fixed width then use 'table-layout:fixed' and 'width:100%' styles to the table.

```
<table class="tableClass" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Test</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

and add the following style

```
tableClass {  
  table-layout: fixed; 
  width:100% !important; 
}
th:nth-child(1){
  width:100px !important;
}
th:nth-child(2){
  width:150px !important;
}
th:nth-child(3){
  width:200px !important;
}
th:nth-child(4){
  width:100px !important;
}
```

Comment: The width is the max-width en min-width in this case. I dont want that the width of number is different when a user is using another screen resolution. I think in my case the table width should stay "100%" and the <th width should be defined in px

Comment: It changed the first table but nothing happend to the second table. Its like the table style has a `width:100%` and there are no styles defined in the `th`

Answer (score 0):

`table cell` always take width according to content, instead of `width` you can use `max-width`. it will work. Check updated snippet below...

Or you can check updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buoey40L/1/)

```html
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab_content1" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
  <table id="employee_grid1" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="max-width:10px">Number</th>
        <th style="max-width:50px">Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th style="max-width:100px"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_content2" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
  <table id="employee_grid2" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="max-width:10px">Number</th>
        <th style="max-width:50px">Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th style="max-width:100px"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It is still the same. It works only for the first table

Comment: Thats weard. It looks working on JSfiddle. But when I insert the rows with javascript the styles dont work. Number in the first `<th>` is `10px`. Number in the second table is something like `25px`

Answer (score 0):

The cells of a table can not take a width less than its contents if there are no spaces between the words. so, you can use `word-break: break-word;` to force the line wrap (but this is not recomended). The ideal is to choose a minimum width matches your content.

Comment: Thats not the problem. The data for table one is the same as the second table

Comment: The style of the two tables is identical. And it's obvious because you have using the same style. Can you add screenshot plz